# Input Validation using Multiple Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text field in which users can enter numerical field with numerical operators. Following is a set of examples for valid input

```
1. > 3
2. >= 3
3. < 3
4. <= 3
5. <> 3 (NOT)
6. 3 to 5 (RANGE)
7. <> 3 to 5 (NOT RANGE)
```

I've the following logic which works. I iterate through each `regex` on `keyup`. I wanna know is there more elegant and better way to do this?

```
function myFunction() {
    var x, text;

    // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
    x = document.getElementById("numb").value;
    var arrRegex = new Array("^>=\\d+$", "^<=\\d+$", "^>\\d+$", "^<\\d+$", "^\\d+$", "^<> \\d+$", "^<> \\d+ to \\d+$", "^\\d+ to \\d+$");
    c = false;
    for (i = 0; i < arrRegex.length; i++) {
        var regex = new RegExp(arrRegex[i]);
        if (regex.test(x)) {
            c = true;
        }
    }
    if (c == true) {
        document.getElementById("numb").style.backgroundColor = "green";

    } else {
        document.getElementById("numb").style.backgroundColor = "red";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `RegExp` as value of `pattern` attribute at `<input>` element, use `css` `:invalid` to style `background` property of element; toggle `className` at element at `input`, `focus` events if element `.value.length === 0` or `:not(:focus)` at `css`, set `background` to `unset !important`, else remove `className` to apply only `css` `:valid`, `:invalid` styles

```css
input:invalid {
  background: red;
}
input:valid {
  background: green;
}
input:not(:focus), .clear {
  background: unset !important;
}
```

```html
<input pattern="^(|>=\d+$|<=\d+$|>\d+$|<\d+$|\d+$|<> \d+$|<> \d+ to \d+$|\d+ to \d+)$">

<script>
  var input = document.querySelector("input[pattern]")
  input.onfocus = input.oninput = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("clear", this.value.length === 0)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: the default with no input is green which is not desirable.

Comment: @skeptic01 See updated post; added `required` attribute to handle no input. What should default `background` be set to with no input?

Answer (score 0):

You can use or (`|`) in your regex to combine them into one:

```
var regex = /^(>=\d+|<=\d+|>\d+|<\d+|\d+|<> \d+|<> \d+ to \d+|\d+ to \d+)$/;
var isValid = regex.test(x);
```

Comment: is performance different if i iterate vs have a multiple regex separated by | ?

Comment: I'm not sure; might vary depending on JavaScript engine, but my hunch is that it would perform slightly better.